# Count connected components in binary image using openCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

How do I find the **number of connected components** in a binary image?
I do not need the mask of their pixels or other properties.
I know I can use labeling and then count all blobs, but it seems redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *need* to know which are the connected components before counting them.

You can get the number directly from [cv::connectedComponents](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaedef8c7340499ca391d459122e51bef5):

```
cv::Mat1b bw; // your black and white image

cv::Mat1i labels;
int n_labels = cv::connectedComponents(bw, labels);

// Note that one label is the background
int n_connected_components = n_labels - 1;
```

Comment: Do you think this is the fastest way, if all I need is 'n_connected_components'

Answer (score 2):

If you have a good seed-filling algorithm, you can scan the image and start filling with the background color every time you meet a foreground pixel.

The number of components is the number of fillings.

Comment: Not a good idea. You're basically suggesting a very slow algorithm to find connected components.

Comment: @Miki: your mistake. This is a linear-time process, the number of operations is at most proportional to the number of pixels. On the other hand, the traditional method relies on union-find,leading to worst-case complexity O(N Log*N). What makes you think it is slow ?

Comment: If I understand correctly your method, you need to: 1) scan the image to find a foreground pixel, 2) flood-fill with that seed, 3) repeat from 1) until no seed is found. If you flood with a new value every time instead of using the background value, you get a connected component algorithm. Which I implemented time ago and is quite slow.  You're probably right about complexities (I can't tell actually), but I'd love to see your implementation running faster than `connectedComponents`. I'm here to learn, so if I'm wrong please tell me ;)

Comment: @Miki: no, you don't repeat from 1), that would be terrible. You continue from where you were.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll miss some cc

Comment: @Miki: why would I ? This is bulletproof.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I misread. Then I'm even more convinced that this is exactly a CCL algoritm, and so you cannot beat `connectedComponents`. I can't wait to see an implementation to prove I'm wrong ;). However have my +1 for the nice idea